# Ansible module No JSON object could be decoded

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests, ansible-2.x

I'm not very experinced in Python thus I apologise if this is trivial.

I'm running following code in Python2.7:

```
from ansible.module_utils.basic import *
import requests

data = { SOME DATA }
headers = {"X-Access-Key": "TOKEN"}
url = "http://API_URL.json
result = requests.post(url, json.dumps(data), headers=headers)

response = result.json()
```

which works as expected and returns:

```
>>> print(result.json())
{u'response': {u'status': 10385, u'message': u'Virtual volume Hello-World already exists in the recycle bin for pool Shared_1'}}
```

However running the same code as part of Ansible(2.3.0.0) module. Causes following error:

```
The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ansible__Gs0dz/ansible_module_zadara_create_volume.py", line 72, in <module>
    main()
  File "/tmp/ansible__Gs0dz/ansible_module_zadara_create_volume.py", line 66, in main
    has_changed, result = choice_map.get(module.params['state'])(module.params)
  File "/tmp/ansible__Gs0dz/ansible_module_zadara_create_volume.py", line 41, in crate_volume
    response = result.json()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 894, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "failed": true, 
    "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/tmp/ansible__Gs0dz/ansible_module_zadara_create_volume.py\", line 72, in <module>\n    main()\n  File \"/tmp/ansible__Gs0dz/ansible_module_zadara_create_volume.py\", line 66, in main\n    has_changed, result = choice_map.get(module.params['state'])(module.params)\n  File \"/tmp/ansible__Gs0dz/ansible_module_zadara_create_volume.py\", line 41, in crate_volume\n    response = result.json()\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py\", line 894, in json\n    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py\", line 339, in loads\n    return _default_decoder.decode(s)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py\", line 364, in decode\n    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py\", line 382, in raw_decode\n    raise ValueError(\"No JSON object could be decoded\")\nValueError: No JSON object could be decoded\n", 
    "module_stdout": "", 
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", 
    "rc": 0
}
```

Using trial and error method I managed to figure out that Ansible module doesn't like the part **response = result.json()**

which is bizzare since I'm running a ripoff of this code [github_repo-py](https://gist.github.com/toast38coza/19f59ed54c355d9f486c#file-github_repo-py)

Is it possible that ansible doesn't like the format of the URL or becasue the return value is a nested json? For this particular API I need to call the `http://api.json` to get the reply in json.

I need the `response = result.json()` so I can iterate over the return values. Anyides how to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Judging from [this example](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/dev_guide/developing_modules_general.html#building-a-simple-module), an Ansible module is expected to send its output to `stdout`.

So this should work:

```
import sys
... your existing code here ...
result.json().dumps(sys.stdout)
```

Or, if you don't need to alter the JSON in any way, you can `print result.content` directly.